# Django CSS only works on certain elements

Tags: html, css, django, django-staticfiles

I've just added some CSS the my django project in a static folder and it only works on some elements. The file is loaded on the site but when I try to make changes to the paragraph element nothing happens. When I edit the body element in the external style sheet it does have an effect on the style. Here is my css and HTML:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
    <title>Would-be Username</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/test.css'%}">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ current_user.userprofile.profile_picture.url }}">
    <p>Username: Would-be Username</p>
    <p>Name: {{ current_user.userprofile.first_name }} {{ current_user.userprofile.last_name }}</p>
    <p>Email: {{ current_user.username }}</p>
    <a href="{{ request.path }}edit/">Edit</a>
    <a href="/reset-password/">Forgot your password?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8"
p {
    color: red;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

The body margin changes, and I can change the color of the text when I add

```
color: red;
```

to the body. However, no matter what I do to 'p', nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong that won't let me edit the 'p' tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very trivial mistake - You need a `;` after the first line:

```
@charset "UTF-8"
```

should be

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Here is [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f6fmq4w/)

Comment: *facepalm*. Damn. This has been bugging me for the last hour... Thanks man :D